# How do I use gcloud with a service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm having trouble getting `gcloud` to access my project as a service account

1. Installed the `gcloud` sdk for Windows on my local machine
2. Created a new service account on Google Cloud Platform console
3. Gave the service account the `Compute Admin` role
4. Authorized `gcloud` as the service account:

   `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=keyfile.json`
5. Issued the command

   `gcloud compute zones list`

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.zones.list) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Required 'compute.zones.list' permission for '<project id>'
```

I verified the `Compute Admin` role has the proper `compute.zones.list` permission.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by recreating the service account.

It seems there's a screen that asks about the roles you want the service account to have as you create it. I originally assigned the roles after the fact.